# rxJava: how to execute multiple Maybes simultaneously

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I want to merge three Maybes together, as follows:

```
return Maybe.merge(
    aOneSecondTask(),
    aFiveSecondTask(),
    aTenSecondTask()
).firstElement();
```

Each of the tasks does a `Thread.sleep()` for the appropriate amount of time, then logs the current time just before returning.

When I run this code, the logs look like this:

```
Starting at 13:26:38
Finishing one-second task at 13:26:39
Finishing five-second task at 13:26:44
Finishing ten-second task at 13:26:54
```

[The docs for Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Maybe.html) suggest that this method should run all the Maybes at once. I'd therefore expect the entire thing to take no more than 10 seconds. Instead, it takes 16 seconds - each task doesn't start until the previous one is finished.

How can I fire off all three tasks simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have only a single-threaded scheduler, so while your `Maybe`s are scheduled to run concurrently, they actually run in series. Don't use blocking calls like `Thread.sleep()` in a reactive environment. In this case, as you are just simulating a slow process, use something like `delay()` to add the required delay to each `Maybe`.